# Visual studio 2013 tab wrapping glitch

Tags: visual-studio-2013, tabs

I have pinned about 7 documents and they almost fill the tab strip, leaving space for only one more document to be opened (depending on the length of the filename) on that tab strip. Then when files are automatically opened as I cycle through "Find Results" or "Find Symbol Results" windows then, depending on the length of the filename, the new tab goes onto a second tab strip.

The issue I am seeing is that Visual Studio gets itself into a mess and is stuck in a loop of moving the tab from the 1st strip to the 2nd strip. I can do nothing in visual studio except watch the tabs dance. I end up having to kill Visual Studio - via Task Manager.

It is just continuously cycling from this:
[image: Single row tab strip]

to this:
[image: Double row tab strip]

Is this a known issue? Is there a solution other than not pinning "too many" documents!

Comment: Report bugs at connect.microsoft.com

Comment: Thanks @Hans. I have done so [here](https://connect.microsoft.com/VisualStudio/feedback/details/1036231/visual-studio-2013-tab-wrapping-glitch). I will leave this open and update/delete depending on what I get back from Microsoft

Comment: Still an issue in VS2015

Comment: I cannot believe this is still happening, even on VS2015. Plus, the Connect post about the issue is closed!

Comment: To anyone who encounters this problem and doesn't want to kill VS process: Try to force different desktop resolution. For me it was as easy as reconnecting RDP using 800x600 as remote desktop size. This forces window resize so the loop will break for 99% (there is still some chance for it to loop in other resolution, but then try yet another one).

Comment: I wonder if the dancing tabs will ever be fixed in 2015...

Comment: @thecoolmacdude - Not only that it wasn't fixed in 2015, it exists on 2017 as well!

Answer (score 12, accepted):

This is caused by an issue in the current version of Pro Power Tools. Details of the issue can be found on connect [here](https://connect.microsoft.com/VisualStudio/feedback/details/1036231/visual-studio-2013-tab-wrapping-glitch).

The (obvious) suggested workarounds are:

1. Display pinned tabs on a separate row from unpinned tabs (Tools > Options > Environment > Tabs and Windows > Show pinned tabs in a separate row).
2. Unpin some tabs, or pin some more tabs.
3. Change the width of the document well containing the tabs, either by resizing the outer window or resizing windows docked to the left or right of the document well.